# I have 2 tables Table A and Table B. There is common data in both tables. But after I run an inner join it is not retrieving any data

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables Table A and Table B. There is common data in both tables. But after I run an inner join it is not retrieving any data.

Comment: Bummer. What is your question?

Comment: Can you show the sql query (maybe wrong `ON` condition)? which dbms (mysql, tsql, oracle)?

Comment: select * from  [dbo].[Main_vw] z
inner join [dbo].[Customer_Type_Details] c
on z.Syt_id = c.System_id
and z.Cust_no = c.Sys_cust_no

Comment: If I use "or" instead of "and" it retrieves some data. But I am looking to apply both conditions.

Answer (score -1):

You are going to see duplicate name errors. Hence you need to either do c.*, z.* instead of * only.